# Codeigniter update form

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine

I'm really new to CI and have been trying to create an update form class today, but I'm running into a dead end. I have my functions set up to create the form and publish the data to  the database, I now need to be able to update this.

My edit form function is below:

```
public function edit_event()
{

    $vars = array();

    $data['form_url'] = $this->form_url;

    if ($form_id = $this->EE->input->get('form_id'))
    {
        $data['form_id'] = $form_id;
    }

    return $this->EE->load->view('edit_event', $data, TRUE);
}
```

and the edit_event file loaded within the function is:

```
<?php

    $this->EE=& get_instance();

    $this->load->helper('form');

        $attributes = array('class' => 'event_form', 'id' => 'my_event_form');

    echo form_open($form_url.AMP.'method=update_form', $attributes);

        $this->EE->load->library('table');
        $this->EE->table->set_heading(
            'Preference',
            'Setting'
        );



        $query = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT * FROM exp_events WHERE id = '$form_id'");

        foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
            {

                $this->EE->table->add_row(
                    form_label('Application Key', 'app_key'),
                    form_input('app_key',$row['app_key'])
                );

                $this->EE->table->add_row(
                    form_label('Access Token', 'access_token'),
                    form_input('access_token',$row['access_token'])
                );

                $this->EE->table->add_row(
                    form_label('User Key', 'user_key'),
                    form_input('user_key',$row['user_key'])
                );

            }

        echo $this->EE->table->generate();


        echo form_reset('reset', 'Clear Form');
        echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Submit Post!');


    echo form_close();

?>
```

I then have my update form function:

```
public function update_form()

{

    $form_id = $this->EE->input->get('form_id');

    $data['form_id'] = $form_id;

    $form_data = array(
        'app_key'        => $this->EE->input->post('app_key'),
        'access_token'   => $this->EE->input->post('access_token'),
        'user_key'       => $this->EE->input->post('user_key')
    );


    $this->EE->db->where('id', $form_id);       
    $this->EE->db->update('exp_events', $form_data);


    $this->EE->functions->redirect($this->base_url);

}
```

When removing the $form_if option I can get the data to update, but it updates for every single item in the database. I obviously need this to only update the data with the form id of the form being edited.

As it stands, when I submit the update form, I get redirected to my $base_url which is correct, but no data gets updated, therefore I am clearly doing something wrong when defining the form id?

As I said I'm new to this, so if anyone notices any preferred methods feel free to let me know :).

Any pointers appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include a 'hidden' field in your form, with the form_id. At the moment your 'form_id' is not part of your input, so when you go and get the form_id it is failing.

change

```
    echo $this->EE->table->generate();
    echo form_reset('reset', 'Clear Form');
    echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Submit Post!');
```

to

```
    echo $this->EE->table->generate();
    echo form_hidden('form_id', $form_id);
    echo form_reset('reset', 'Clear Form');
    echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Submit Post!');
```

Comment: thanks for the response. That makes sense!! I have added the hidden field, yet when I submit the form the fields are not updating. As soon as I remove the $form_id = $this->EE->input->get('form_id');$data['form_id'] = $form_id; from the update_form function, the data updates for all form at once. So I must be going wrong with the EE->db->update somewhere.

Comment: You're looking at GET when you should be looking at POST. `$form_id = $this->EE->input->post('form_id');`.

Comment: AHA! Gotcha, thanks Derek!! TheShiftExchange your comments also helped a lot, so thanks :)